# como puedo ignorar un cuarto valor de un ARGV en ruby?

Tags: ruby

Buenas tardes chicos tengo una duda, estoy realizando un ejercicio de eleecion sobre 4 numeros ver cual es el mayor, me gustaria que al no colocar el 4to valor lo ignore totalmente y tome el mayor de 3, no se como colocarlo en mi linea de codigo soy nuevo en ruby.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código relevante (agrégalo a tu pregunta)?

Answer (score 0):

Sé que ya ha pasado tiempo desde tu pregunta pero acá te va una respuesta (para ti o para quien lea esto después).

En Ruby puedes crear una función con parámetros que, en caso de que no existan al llamar la función, toman el valor que quieras tú.

Por ejemplo:

```
def select_higher(one, two, three, four=nil)
  [one, two, three, four].compact.max
end
```

Si te fijas el cuarto parámetro de la función tiene un `= nil` esto quiere decir que en caso de que se llame la función con solo 3 parámetros, el cuarto tomará el valor `nil` (o nulo, en Ruby).

En cuanto a la función, solo crea un arreglo con los 4 parámetros.

El [`compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-compact) quita los valores nulos de un arreglo.

El [`max`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) obtiene el mayor valor (pueden ser incluso palabras).

Te recomiendo que le des click a los enlaces y leas los módulos.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Saludos!

PD: Si la respuesta te ha ayudado, dale un voto a favor, ayudaría a los demás a encontrar la respuesta correcta.